# simplexml_load_file not working with cron job

Tags: php, xml, cron

I have this cron job on my server that runs this PHP script every 30 minutes. The Cron job looks like this:

`*/30 * * * * wget https://example.com/cron.php -O /var/log/cronerror.txt`

The Cron job works, the PHP script does several things (send email, update database etc) and this is working fine.

What is not working is a part of the script using `simplexml_load_file` loading an external URL. Opening this URL is supposed to send a SMS-message.

When I open the script in my browser, the SMS-message is sent and everything works. But when the cron job executes the script, it is not sent. Seems like it cant open URL through `simplexml_load_file`. Any ideas why/other solutions?

Comment: Check the PHP error logs on the server first of all.

Comment: Make sure that the PHP version being used by the browser is the same version used from cron and that they are both using the same PHP ini file.

Comment: probably some path problem

Comment: Of course, why didn't I think about that... :| It gave an error in the logs, `I/O warning : failed to load external entity`. The URL have an variable (from another file) in it which the Cron job apparently cant access. Hardcoded the URL now and it works!